# Updating PhD applications with new awards / publications?

Tags: graduate-admissions

I’ve submitted all of my PhD applications, and recently competed in and won (along with the rest of my research group) a national (USA) government-funded research challenge in my field. I will also have a few more preprints and perhaps an accepted publication by the time admissions decisions are made. Is there a set of best practices for informing the admissions committees about such updates as they come in?

Comment: You have to ask individual universities what their policies are for updating applications. They might allow it or not, but you have to ask to know.